# Replacing a certain char with another char

Tags: javascript, node.js

So mobile phones send quotation marks with the ASCII value 8220 and it's messing with my regex expression. So I want to replace at the ASCII character codes 8220 with ASCII character code 34.

Code:

```
daaa = "“hello there“";
daaa.replace(/“/g, "\"");
mydata1 = daaa.charCodeAt(0);
mydata2 = daaa.charCodeAt(12);
console.log("mydata: ", mydata1, mydata2);
```

Console when I run it:

```
mydata:  8220 8220
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reassigning `daaa` variable

> With `replace` the original string is left unchanged.

```js
let daaa = "“hello there“";
daaa = daaa.replace(/“/g, "\"");
mydata1 = daaa.charCodeAt(0);
mydata2 = daaa.charCodeAt(12);
console.log("mydata: ", mydata1, mydata2);
```